# USB flash drive still showing in This PC when disconnected

Tags: windows, usb, windows-10, freeze

Sometimes (not always) when removing my USB flash drive it still shows in "This PC" and the disk space usage bar is missing:

[image]

When reconnecting it, the disk space usage bar is still missing and opening it opens an empty folder. The PC also doesn't recognize any USB devices I connect after this happens. USB devices connected before still work until reconnected. After this happens, the PC also fails to reboot (hangs on Restarting) and won't power off without forcing it to. "Scan for hardware changes" in Device Manager also doesn't work. Everything else still works fine. 
I'm on Windows 10 Pro.

EDIT:

The answers in the other post that my post is a "duplicate" of, don't solve my problem. The data on my flash drive is fine.

Comment: Did you use the "usb safely remove" method when removing the usb device?

Comment: No - i did not safely remove it

Comment: Does it persist after a restart of the PC?

Comment: I can't restart the PC without holding the power button or pressing the reset button, but after resetting it, everything is normal - until it happens again.

Comment: Try using the safely remove every time, see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Strange, because it doesn't happen every time...

Answer (score -1):

Disconnect your USB from device the computer. Download [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html), open it, find your USB device, then right-click on it and choose "Uninstall Selected Devices".

Comment: Doesn't do anything. It's still in the list.

Comment: When you uninstalled your USB device in USBDeview and reconnected it, did Windows not reinstall the driver?

Comment: Do you have EHCI Hand-Off enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: I only have XHCI Hand-Off and that's disabled. I don't think USBDeview uninstalled the driver, the flash drive still was in the list.